# How to place a fixed background for div?

Tags: html, css

I am making cordova project for android, also for improve performance purpose, I am convert all html files into one file, so I can not able to apply any class or set background images in **<body>** tag. Also I need to set background image for **<div>** tag.
I tried with the following code, but the image not fully set into background, top,bottom,left and right side have some space and the background image will little scroll in the end. If the image is **stretch**, that is not a problem.

From the below output you can not able to understand my whole problem, so please copy whole code and crate a new html file in your system and check in mobile view.

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<style>
.fxdback
{
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: scroll;
    background: url(https://s4.postimg.org/rfdxbny59/menus-min.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
} 
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="fxdback">
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
This ist he test<br/>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try in this way.

```html
<div id="mytext" style="background: center cover fixed no-repeat url('https://s4.postimg.org/rfdxbny59/menus-min.jpg');">

<!-- Your content here -->

</div>
```

Hope it should work.

Comment: in this way, whole image is scrolling

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to create a parallax effect from what I understand.

you can try this:

```
.bgimg-1 {                              // this is the most important code
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

//this one for image (Logo. Full height)
.bgimg-1 {
    background-image: url('image path');
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

you can put it in separate css file if you are having multiple html and want to keep all files same.

Comment: Whole image is scrolling, this did not fixed the background image.

Comment: @MerbinJoe

Well it worked for me. 
Try this,

    `<div class="bgimg-1>
    <body>
    </body>
    </div>`

and include the css file using 
`<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="path of css file"/>`

Comment: I too tried but not working. 
Go through this link:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_parallax.asp

Comment: the background should be in fixed mode(no scroll). But here background image is scrolling.

Comment: Yes. This is called parallax effect. Its properly working in my projects.